# How to setup a template-engine in ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, template-engine

I want to customize rails scaffolding. For that I want to set up a custom template engine.

Can anyone guide me to set a custom template-engine.

Comment: you can check this how can you customise generators. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a custom template engine to customize rails scaffolding. Depending on what you're trying to do, you can [customize your rails generators](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer) or use a tool such as [rails-composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer) / [rails_apps_composer](https://github.com/RailsApps/rails_apps_composer).

If you're looking to switch the default template engine, for rails 3, you can use `--template-engine` flag. There are also options such as [Tilt](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt/) that provide a layer of abstraction so that it's easier to switch between the leading options.